# Umbraco - DocumentType Field in c#

Tags: c#, umbraco

I'm trying to get an Umbraco Field in c# like this :

```
(String.Format(Umbraco.Field("labelFailure").ToString(), username));
```

But I'm getting the following error :

```
Cannot return the IPublishedContent because the UmbracoHelper was constructed with an UmbracoContext and the current request is not a front-end 
request.
```

I don't know the error and how to resolve it.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to access Umbraco.Field in your custom c# code and not in a view?

Comment: Yes, I want to make a ViewData.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are not in a view you should use GetPropertyValue on the IPublishedContent of the page to get your value:

```
..
using Umbraco.Web;
..

var idPage = 1234; // you should get this dynamically :)
IPublishedContent page = Umbraco.TypedContent(idPage);
var labelFailure = page.GetPropertyValue<string>("labelFailure");
```