# "the UmbracoHelper was constructed with an UmbracoContext and the current request is not a front-end request."

Tags: ajax, pagination, umbraco

I'm trying to implement ajax pagination using Umbraco.

On the server side, I have the following:

```
[System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
public JsonResult pagination(int? page)
{
IEnumerable<IPublishedContent> newsPosts = Umbraco.AssignedContentItem.DescendantOrSelf("news").Children.Where(x => x.IsVisible() && x.DocumentTypeAlias ==     "newsPost").OrderByDescending(x => x.UpdateDate).Take(5);

    //from here on we will be returning the json within which information required for displaying post entries in carousel is included.
    string json = "[some random string]"; //just random string for now.
    return Json(json, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

As you can see, I'm trying to get necessary data from IPublishedContents, but I'm having trouble instantiating this series of IPublishedContents.

And this is the error I'm getting when I access:

*locahost:{port}/umbraco/surface/{controller}/pagination* on Chrome.

```
Cannot return the IPublishedContent because the UmbracoHelper was constructed with an UmbracoContext and the current request is not a front-end request.

Details: System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot return the IPublishedContent because the UmbracoHelper was constructed with an UmbracoContext and the current request is not a front-end request.
```

As I said, I'm making this request from Chrome, which is I think means this request is from the front end, so I'm not sure why I'm getting this error.

In the course of searching I found these

1) [our.umbraco.com forum](https://our.umbraco.com/forum/developers/api-questions/49041-The-UmbracoHelper-was-constructed-with-an-UmbracoContext-and-the-current-request-is-not-a-front-end-request)
2) [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44655299/umbraco-documenttype-field-in-c-sharp)

1. is deserted with no answer, and as for 2, it strikes me that the answer is not quite relevant to my case. I want to instantiate IPublishedContent in the first place.

Mine is Umbraco 7.

and could it be possible to tell me why requests from the front-end are not desirable?

Any hint would be highly appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: if you spotted my answer saying "all I needed to do was to create a new instance of...", please forget it, I thought I did it but realised it was because I just commented out a crucial line

Comment: Does your controller inherit from Surface?

Answer (score 1):

Try getting your node this way.

```
var umbracoHelper = new Umbraco.Web.UmbracoHelper(Umbraco.Web.UmbracoContext.Current);
var yourNode = umbracoHelper.TypedContentAtXPath("umbracoPathtoYourNode");
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps easier to use web api

Create a controller which inherits from UmbracoApiController

```
public class PagedItemsController : UmbracoApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    [ActionName("list")] //Optional see note below
    public IHttpActionResult GetItems([FromUri] int pageNo = 1)
    {
        // Next you need some way of getting the items you need. 
        // I would not return the whole IPublishedContent items.  Rather query those and then use linq Select to transform into a more relevant smaller class (not doing this here)
        // I've just included this for brevity
        var items = _itemService.GetPagedItems(pageNo);

        // Now return the results
        return Ok(items);
    }
}
```

Calls to endpoints in Umbraco follow the format

```
/umbraco/api/{controller}/{endpoint}
```

With the `[ActionName("list")]` above the call to the `GetItems` method will be

```
http://example.com/umbraco/api/PagedItems/list?pageNo=3
```

Without the ActionName attribute the call would be

```
http://exampe.com/umbraco/api/PagedItems/GetItems?pageNo=3
```

With a standard jquery ajax call this will return json without needing to serialise.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but I still cannot instantiate ipublishedcontents within the controller. 
Getting the same, "the Umbraco Helper was constructed with an..." error.


        // Next you need some way of getting the items you need. 
        // I would not return the whole IPublishedContent items.  Rather query those and then use linq Select to transform into a more relevant smaller class (not doing this here)

=>would be great if you could give me a little bit more details (parameters and property names can be just a mock, but would like actual methods.

thanks,

Comment: So are you trying to call this endpoint by putting the url in Chrome address bar? Does your endpoint return anything if you don't include the calls to Umbraco methods?

Comment: thanks for all the information, 
(1) I'm not intending to use the browser to see the result of my controller, so I get your point. 
(2) I was having trouble with the instantiation of Umbraco Helper, and it turns out I should've done "TypedContent" instead of "AssignedContentItem" (I didn't provide enough information, so it's my fault)